# Difference between initializing a Tensorflow Variable using np.zeros and using tf.zeros

Tags: variables, tensorflow, initialization

Are there some differences between initializing a tensorflow Variable using np.zeros and using tf.zeros?

For example, if we take a look at the MNIST softmax tutorial (
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py), the variables W and b are initialized in the following way.

```
  W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
```

Instead of initializing using tf.zeros, the code still works fine if we use np.zeros as follows.

```
  W = tf.Variable(np.zeros([784, 10], dtype=np.float32))
  b = tf.Variable(np.zeros([10], dtype=np.float32))
```

So, I think there might be no difference. But, I tried the following code segment assuming that the following `a` and `b` variables are the same.

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((3, 2)), tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros((3, 2)), tf.float32)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
a.eval()
```

The result of `a.eval()` is as follows:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

But the result of `b.eval()` is as follows:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
```

So, even though the values are the same, there is a difference in dtype. Could you please explain to me why this difference exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most experiments it almost does not matter. You can also provide python list of lists `[[0, 0, ...], ...]`. The difference you see in your `eval` is because [tf.zeros](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros) by default uses `float32`. On the contrary [np.zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) by default uses `float64`. Change one or another and you will not see a difference.

In production code it is better to use `tf.` functions for initialization to reduce the overhead.